# Weird behavior when indenting code in sublime text 3

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

I have this code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'somthing'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['something']], function () {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'somethingelse'], function () {
            Route::group(['prefix' => 'someotherthing'], function () {
                Route::get('something', ['uses' => 'SomethingController@something'); // Here color scheme doesn't show up properly
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In the middle there (where `Route::get` is called), The color scheme doesn't show up properly:

[image]

Anything from that point forward showing in white in default color scheme (doesn't work on other color schemes as well).

[image]

ST3 3114 build, 64bit. OS windows 8.1. Screenshot 2 material theme lighter.

Comment: I appear to have a similar problem with a different color scheme. Is this a Sublime syntax problem? Maybe you should consider searching the Sublime forums on this or open a new thread about it.

Comment: @z3r0ck at your third line you have an extra closing square bracket `]]`, it might be the problem causing it?

Comment: @HL96 Removing it doesn't help. And look closely it's not a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error on line 5 that may be affecting the highlighting:

```
Route::get('something', ['uses' => 'SomethingController@something');
```

is missing a closing square bracket `]`:

```
Route::get('something', ['uses' => 'SomethingController@something']);
```

Using the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) (full disclosure: I'm the author), your original code looks like this:

[image: no closing bracket]

(note the green closing parentheses `)` and curly brackets `}`). With the offending closing square bracket added, it looks like this:

[image: with closing bracket]

You don't indicate which color scheme you're using, so I couldn't compare my results with it, but hopefully adding the missing bracket will help.

Comment: Thanks, But unfortunately the syntax errors have nothing to do with it in my case, Those were introduced when I was removing my original code and just adding an example. Also, I tried this piece of code with various color schemes all have the same effect so far (one way or another) (tried neon too by the way).

Comment: @z3r0ck what version and build of Sublime Text are you using?

Comment: ST3 3114 build, 64bit.

OS windows 8.1.